# What does crop size refer to in DeepLabv3 paper?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, semantic-segmentation

In the paper in which DeepLabv3 is presented, the authors are mentioning that:

*"For atrous convolution with large rates to be effective, large
**crop size** is required; otherwise, the filter weights with large
atrous rate are mostly applied to the padded zero region. We
thus employ **crop size** to be **513** during both training and test
on PASCAL VOC 2012 dataset"*

What does this mean? 
If for example I want to use the Cityscapes dataset for training, considering the idea mentioned by the authors, I should take **513x513** croppings for each example image that is originally **2048x1024**? 
Does the **crop size** refer to something else? Or if not, does it involve other steps/operations too?

I would be really grateful if somebody could clarify this concept and how it is applied during **training** and how it affects the **inference**.

Paper link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05587.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out that indeed the **training** of DeepLabv3 is performed in a patch-based manner which means the usage of a patch with a given **crop size**, that is extracted randomly from an example pair (input, target).


Regarding **validation/testing**, full-size example pairs (input, target) are used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).